# TypeORM: queryBuilder ignores default eager relations

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have noticed that when fetching data with `getRepository().find()`, some relations are already feted by default (eager) according to my definitions in the `Entity`.
This is not the case with Query Builder - in each query, I have to do all the joins and selects again...

for example, I have a `Recipe` entity which has `likes: User[]` relation.
I want to fetch the likes count with each query to this entity.

```js
@Entity()
export class Recipe {

    // some other attribues...

    @ManyToOne(type => User, author => author.recipes, {eager: true})
    @JoinColumn({name: "authorId"})
    author: User;

    @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.id)
    @JoinTable()
    likes: User[];

    likesCount: number;
}
```

I have this code which fetches the recipe with the counter:

```js
return await getRepository(Recipe)
    .createQueryBuilder("recipe")
    .loadRelationCountAndMap("recipe.likesCount", "recipe.likes")
    .where("recipe.id = :id", { id: recipeId })
    .getOne();
```

but, it does not fetch any other **eager** relations, as this simple code does:

```js
await getRepository(Recipe).findOne(recipeId)
```

When is the best approach here? go with QueryBuilder and add all the joins and selects I need, or use a second request after `.find` is done, to fetch only the counter?

I want a good solution that will be easy to do with a list of recipes as well:

```js
        getRepository(Recipe).findAndCount({
            skip: (page * limit) || 0,
            take: limit || 200,
            order: {createdAt: 'DESC'}
        }).then((result) => {
            const [recipes, total] = result;
            response.json({total, items: recipes});
        }).catch(e => next(e));
```